# Get RPY from tfListener

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I want to get the RPY data from my transformation. I have the next code:

```
include <ros/ros.h>
include <tf/tf.h>
include <tf/transform_listener.h>
include <geometry_msgs/TransformStamped.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    ros::init(argc, argv, "tf_listener");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    ROS_INFO_STREAM("Started node tf_listener.");
  
    std::string target_frame, source_frame;
    tf::TransformListener tf_listener;
    tf::StampedTransform transform;
    ros::Rate rate(1.); 

    if (argc < 3) {
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        target_frame = argv[1];
        source_frame = argv[2];
    }    
        
    while (ros::ok()) {
        try {
            tf_listener.lookupTransform(target_frame, source_frame, ros::Time(), transform);

            geometry_msgs::Transform buffer;
            tf::transformTFToMsg(transform, buffer);
            ROS_INFO_STREAM("Transform from " << target_frame << " to " << source_frame << ": " << std::endl << buffer);
            ROS_INFO_STREAM("Distance between transforms: " << transform.getOrigin().length() << " meters.");
        }
        catch (...) {
            ROS_WARN_STREAM("Waiting for transform from " << target_frame << " to " << source_frame);
        }
        rate.sleep();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How can I get it??

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196619/get-rpy-from-tflistener/) by [rcj1986](https://answers.ros.org/users/14706/rcj1986/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2014-11-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please use the block quote method for code blocks. I've edited your question for you.

The tf::Transforms has a [getBasis method to get the tf::Matrix3x3 datatype.](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/tf/html/c++/classtf_1_1Transform.html) On which there are [lots of RPY methods including getRPY](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/tf/html/c++/classtf_1_1Matrix3x3.html)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0